# WCF Service error while browsing svc file

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, iis

I have created a WCF service and added the same as Service reference in another Windows application. It is working fine there. I have created a website and added the as project reference to the Service. Then, while trying to browse the svc file in a browser, its throws an error at my ConnectionString.

`public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TestConnection"].ToString());`

The error message is `Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

What may be the possible error? Please help.

Comment: Show us you config file entry?

Comment: `<appSettings>
  <add key="TestConnection" value="Data Source=PAL01OITSW043\SQLEXPRESS2008;Initial Catalog=Test;user=test;password=test;Connection Timeout=0;" />
 </appSettings>`

Comment: But, I think the value returned during the browsing of svc file is NULL. What may be the reason for that ?

Comment: Can you open the WCF service in a browser without any exceptions?

Comment: Previously there was exceptions because `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TestConnection"]` was getting null. Now I have handled with Convert.ToString. Hence the service is getting started without any exceptions. But, when we try to call a method which access the database, it throws an error `Failed to invoke the service. The service may be offline or inaccessible. Refer to the stack trace for details.`. This may be because that connectionstring is getting as NULL. Any idea why this is getting null in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. Since I'm using that Windows and WCF Service, I need to have specify that in the web.config of service too. Adding the `<appSettings>` tag in the web.config tag resolve my issue. I'm not sure whether this is a correct method or not, but it did made a smile in my face. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no item with a key named `TestConnection` in the `appSettings` section of the configuration file of your service.

Comment: Its already there in the App.Config of the service. `<appSettings>
  <add key="TestConnection" value="Data Source=PAL01OITSW043\SQLEXPRESS2008;Initial Catalog=Test;user=test;password=test;Connection Timeout=0;" />
 </appSettings>`

Comment: But, I think the value returned during the browsing of svc file is NULL. What may be the reason for that ?

Comment: App.config ? If your service is hosted in IIS (as you tagged your question with), the configuration should be a file named `web.config` at the root directory of your IIS Web site (or virtual directory). This file should be the one where your service is looking his configuration up from.

Comment: Is this service be able to call from a windows application ?

Comment: I'm a newbie in WCF. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I have created a WCF Service and added the config file as App.Config. This was working fine with the windows applications. But, now I need to use this service as a web service. So, what all changes are needed to implement the same ?

Comment: Its working fine when I put the appSettings in the Web.Config of the new website created for hosting. I dont know whether it is the correct method. But, Its working!!

Comment: It is correct, if you want to deploy an application that use configuration, you must also deploy the application configuration.

Comment: How do we host this service in the remote IIS server?

Comment: I'm getting an error while I tried to host and browse the service svc file from a remote server. `HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.` Any idea of this error ?

Comment: This is a different question, and you should try to search for your question before asking them, I just put your message in google and got plenty of leads.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have placed the connectionstring in `<AppSettings/>` or `<connectionstring>`

Comment: Its in the appSettings only. `<appSettings> <add key="TestConnection" value="Data Source=PAL01OITSW043\SQLEXPRESS2008;Initial Catalog=Test;user=test;password=test;Connection Timeout=0;" /> </appSettings>`

Comment: How do we host this service in the remote IIS server?